# Showing Result Dynamically

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a table 'products'. The columns are 'id' and 'product_name' etc. Now how can I set the URL like this with codeigniter?

localhost/product/details/apple-iphone-7-50064584

Now here, product name is Apple Iphone 7 and id is 50064584. How can I combine them and show the result dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide assumes you are using the Apache web server.

**Step 1:** Remove index.php

Open /application/config/config.php

Change this...

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To this...

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Save the file.

**Step 2:** Add .htaccess file

Create a .htaccess file in the same directory as your main index.php file with the following contents...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Save the file.

**Step 3:** Configuring Apache

Locate your Apache configuration file (httpd.conf). For me this is located at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Ensure that there is no comment before the directive to load mod_rewrite.

For example, if you see this...

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Change it to this...

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Save the file.

Restart apache to allow the changes to take effect.

**Step 4:** Create Your Controller

Create a new PHP file in your /application/controllers/ directory and name it Products.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Products extends CI_Controller
{

    public function detail($id)
    {

        // Retrieve The Product From The Database
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        // Product Found
        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {

            $product = $query->row();

            // Pass The Product Details To The Product Details View Page And Display The Page
            $this->load->view('product-details', $product);

        // Product Not Found
        } else {

            // Display 404 Page
            show_404();

        }

    }

}
```

Save the file.

**Step 6:** Create Your View File

Create a new PHP file in your /application/views/ directory and name it product-details.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $product_name; ?></title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1><?php echo $product_name; ?></h1>

    <!-- Add the rest of your HTML here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Save the file.

**Step 7:** Set Up Your Route.

Map the URL that you want to use to the "detail" method of the "Products" controller.

Open /application/config/routes.php

Add the following line...

```
$route['product/details/(:any)-(:num)']  = 'products/detail/$2';
```

Save the file.

Enter the following URL in your browser: http://localhost/product/details/apple-iphone-7-50064584

Voilà!

Comment: Thanks, you're master!

Comment: @codeigniter You are very welcome. Thanks for the compliment!

Answer (score 0):

localhost/product/details/apple-iphone-7-50064584

domain/appname/controller/method/arguments

```
class Details {

  function show($name, $id) {
       $this->load->view('hello);
  }
}
```

will produce an url like "localhost/product/details/$product/$id" if you removed 'index.php' of your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate. Looks like your question is a little "wide".

To answer properly, I would write a complete tutorial.

Where are you got problem? Query, Active Records, URI segments?...